# Simplify: $\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How to get from: $$\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)$$

To: $$4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$$
?

Comment: $\sin^2(x) = 1-\cos^2(x)$

Comment: use the identity $1=\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)$

Comment: To produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$3\sin^2(x)=3-3\cos^2(x)$$ so
$$\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)=\cos(x)\big (\cos^2(x)-3+3\cos^2(x)\big )=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

We can simplify it further to $\cos (3x)$.

Indeed,

$$(\cos x + i \sin x)^3 = (e^{ix})^3 = e^{3 i x} = \cos 3x + i \sin 3x$$

and the result follows by comparing the real component of the left and right sides.

Answer (score 0):

> Proof: $$\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)=\cos(3x)$$

$$\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ and $\cos^3(x)=\frac{3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)}{4}$:

---

$$\frac{3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)}{4}-3\cos(x)\cdot\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cos(x)}{4}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{4}-3\cos(x)\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}\right)=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cos(x)}{4}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{4}+\frac{3\cos(x)\cos(2x)}{2}-\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\cos(x)\cos(2x)=\frac{\cos(x-2x)+\cos(x+2x)}{2}=\frac{\cos(-x)+\cos(3x)}{2}$:

---

$$\frac{3\cos(x)}{4}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{4}-\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}+\frac{3\left(\cos(-x)+\cos(3x)\right)}{4}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$:

---

$$\frac{3\cos(x)}{4}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{4}-\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}+\frac{3\left(\cos(x)+\cos(3x)\right)}{4}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cos(x)}{4}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{4}-\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}+\frac{3\cos(x)}{4}+\frac{3\cos(3x)}{4}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)+3\cos(x)+3\cos(3x)}{4}-\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}+\cos(3x)-\frac{3\cos(x)}{2}=\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=\cos(3x)$$

Comment: Does not answer the question.